# Проблема нулей: теряются старшие нули при выводе

Tags: c++, битовые-операции, hex

значение переменной в hex 0x0004e667
на выводе и в расчетах используется только значащие цифры 4е667, а нули теряются. при конкатенации и битовых операциях из-за этого сбиваются все расчёты. если подобрать значения переменных в которых нет нулей в начале, все считает правильно.

как в с++ указать что значение переменные беззнаковые размером 32 бит должно всегда представлять 32 бита даже если 31 бит из них нулевой?

```
unsigned long int x = 0x0000ffff;
cout << hex << x;
```

где 4 нуля в начале на выводе?

```
unsigned long int e = 0x010e527f, b = 0x0005688c, c = 0x0f83d9ab, a, z;
z = (e&b) ^ ((~e) & c);
a = z&e;
cout << hex << z << endl << a;
```

где нули?

старшие биты нужно оставлять даже если они нули [image]

сорри,  с телефона очень неудобно писать

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;        
unsigned long int ma(unsigned long int a, unsigned long int b, unsigned long int c) {
    unsigned long int result = (a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c);
    return result;    
}        
unsigned long int ch(unsigned long int a, unsigned long int b, unsigned long int c) {
    unsigned long int result = (a & b) ^ ((~a) & c);
    return result;    
}    
unsigned long int sum0(unsigned long int a) {
    unsigned long int result = ((a >> 2) | (a << 30)) ^ ((a >> 13) | (a << 19)) ^ ((a >> 22) | (a << 10));
    return result;    
}    
unsigned long int sum1(unsigned long int a) {
    unsigned long int result = ((a >> 6) | (a << 26)) ^ ((a >> 11) | (a << 21)) ^ ((a >> 25) | (a << 7));
    return result;     
}        
unsigned long int S0(unsigned long int a) {
    unsigned long int result = ((a >> 7) | (a << 25)) ^ ((a >> 18) | (a << 14)) ^ (a >> 3);
    return result;     
}
unsigned long int S1(unsigned long int a) {
    unsigned long int result = ((a >> 17) | (a << 15)) ^ ((a >> 19) | (a << 13)) ^ (a >> 10);
    return result;     
}
int main() {
    const unsigned long int n[8] = {0x6A09E667, 0xBB67AE85, 0x3C6EF372, 0xA54FF53A, 0x510E527F, 0x9B05688C, 0x1F83D9AB, 0x5BE0CD19};
    const unsigned long int k[64] = 
    { 
    0x428A2F98, 0x71374491, 0xB5C0FBCF, 0xE9B5DBA5, 0x3956C25B, 0x59F111F1, 0x923F82A4, 0xAB1C5ED5,
    0xD807AA98, 0x12835B01, 0x243185BE, 0x550C7DC3, 0x72BE5D74, 0x80DEB1FE, 0x9BDC06A7, 0xC19BF174,
    0xE49B69C1, 0xEFBE4786, 0x0FC19DC6, 0x240CA1CC, 0x2DE92C6F, 0x4A7484AA, 0x5CB0A9DC, 0x76F988DA,
    0x983E5152, 0xA831C66D, 0xB00327C8, 0xBF597FC7, 0xC6E00BF3, 0xD5A79147, 0x06CA6351, 0x14292967,
    0x27B70A85, 0x2E1B2138, 0x4D2C6DFC, 0x53380D13, 0x650A7354, 0x766A0ABB, 0x81C2C92E, 0x92722C85,
    0xA2BFE8A1, 0xA81A664B, 0xC24B8B70, 0xC76C51A3, 0xD192E819, 0xD6990624, 0xF40E3585, 0x106AA070,
    0x19A4C116, 0x1E376C08, 0x2748774C, 0x34B0BCB5, 0x391C0CB3, 0x4ED8AA4A, 0x5B9CCA4F, 0x682E6FF3,
    0x748F82EE, 0x78A5636F, 0x84C87814, 0x8CC70208, 0x90BEFFFA, 0xA4506CEB, 0xBEF9A3F7, 0xC67178F2};
    unsigned long int m[8], t1, t2, w1[64], w[64] = 
    {0x00000020, 0x6a156a39, 0xe3c18a30, 0xb363eb38, 0x46d1353a, 0xf8d1157d, 0x39107100, 0x00000000, 
     0x00000000, 0x41d4be32, 0x227fcf9b, 0xe1af3c3e, 0x6aa8e117, 0x67301169, 0x17daf4ad, 0x3a738091}; // block M1

    for (int i = 16; i <= 63; i++) {w[i] = S1(w[i-2]) + w[i-7] + S0(w[i-15]) + w[i-16];} 

    unsigned long int a = n[0], b = n[1], c = n[2], d = n[3], e = n[4], f = n[5], g = n[6], h = n[7]; // massiv?

        for (int t = 0; t < 64; ++t) {
            t1 = h + sum1(e) + ch(e, f, g) + k[t] + w[t];
            t2 = sum0(a) + ma(a, b, c);
            h = g; g = f; f = e; e = d + t1; d = c; c = b; b = a;
            a = t1 + t2;} // add in array n[]
        m[0] = n[0] + a, m[1] =n[1] + b, m[2] =n[2] + c, m[3] =n[3] + d, m[4] =n[4] + e, m[5] =n[5] + f, m[6] =n[6] + g, m[7] =n[7] + h;
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        cout << hex << m[x] << "   " << endl; // hash M1 block

    unsigned long int w1[64] = 
    {0xca5770f2, 0xa1961d5a, 0xf6d00018, 0xea12e722, 0x80000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 
     0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000280}; // block M2
    }
    for (int i = 16; i <= 63; i++) {w1[i] = S1(w1[i-2]) + w1[i-7] + S0(w1[i-15]) + w1[i-16];} 
    a = n[0], b = n[1], c = n[2], d = n[3], e = n[4], f = n[5], g = n[6], h = n[7]; 
    for (int t = 0; t < 64; ++t) {
            t1 = h + sum1(e) + ch(e, f, g) + k[t] + w1[t];
            t2 = sum0(a) + ma(a, b, c);
            h = g; g = f; f = e; e = d + t1; d = c; c = b; b = a; a = t1 + t2;} 
        m[0] += a, m[1] += b, m[2] += c, m[3] += d, m[4] += e, m[5] += f, m[6] += g, m[7] += h;
        cout << hex << m[0] << "   " << m[1] << "   " << m[2] << "   " << m[3] << "   " << m[4] << "   " << m[5] << "   " << m[6] << "   " << m[7];
    return 0;
}
```

вот этот код верно считает block M1, а блок М2 неверно, я подумал что это проблема нулей 
в начале описаны функции, затем много переменных, сам код всего 15 20 строк

Comment: Битовые операции сбиавются? Не верю! Минимальный пример в студию! А беззнаковое 32-битное это с шансами unsigned long

Comment: Чушь какая-то написана. Нули могут теряться при выводе, но при расчетах они не могут "теряться" никак.

Comment: unsigned long int x = 0x0000ffff ; cout << hex << x; где 4нуля в начале на выводе?

Comment: unsigned long int e = 0x010e527f, b = 0x0005688c, c = 0x0f83d9ab, a, z;
    z = (e&b) ^ ((~e) & c);
    a = z&e;
    cout << hex << z << endl << a; //где нули?

Comment: так это проблема вывода, а не расчетов, битовые операции же идут в регистрах процессора в двоичном виде. Так что говорить, что "_сбиваются все расчеты_" не верно, считает то правильно. И единственный вопрос как корректно вывести результат в человеко-читаемом формате, на который уже ответили ниже ...

Comment: Смешались в кучу строки, биты...

Comment: действительно ничего не теряется, код кривой просто
но с выводом надо будет ещё поразмышлять
как вариант вывод значений элементов массива, если выводится не 8 символов, значит добавить нули в начале до 8

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов спасибо это очень полезный комментарий, реально очень благодарен

Comment: @AnT очень благодарен за этот потрясающий комментарий, реально очень помогло

Answer (score 2):

По-умолчанию ведущие нули не печатаются. Если хотите их напечатать то надо прямо задать параметры:

```
cout << setw(static_cast<int>(sizeof(x) * 2)) << setfill('0') << hex << x << dec;
```

Кроме того, если вам нужны целые определенной длины, то следует использовать целочисленные типы фиксированной длины из стандартной библиотеки. т.е вместо `unsigned long int` следует писать `uint32_t`.

Comment: как это можно сделать глобально для всей программы? cout << setw(static_cast<int>(sizeof(x) * 2)) << setfill('0') << hex << x << dec;

Comment: @vbujym Никак. Можно съэкономить сделав класс-обертку для целых чисел с перегруженным оператором `<<` чтобы не писать все форматирование каждый раз.

Comment: спасибо, надо все же искать решение проблемы с этим кодом, непонятно почему неверно считает второй блок М2

Comment: какую библиотеку добавить в #include, с одним  <iostream> не пропускает такой код